# Use while loop inside pynput's mouse listener

Tags: python, while-loop, mouselistener, pynput, mouse-listeners

The while loop returns true even when I have let go of the left mouse button which would make pressed = false. I don't know how to break out of the loop to update the pressed value.

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

control = Controller()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        while pressed == True:
            print(pressed)

with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Is there any way to update the loop so it knows when pressed = false.

Comment: don't use `while` loop but normal `if not pressed`. When you run `while` loop then it can't run `on_click` again and it can't stop this loop. And if you really need to run some code in loop then run it in separated thread.

Answer (score 4):

If you really have to run some loop then you have to do it in separted `thread` because if you run it in `on_click` then you block `listener` and it can't run another `on_click`

`on_click` should start loop in `thread` and use global variable to control when it should stop.

```
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import threading

control = Controller()

running = False

def process():
    print('start')
    count = 0
    while running:
        print(count)
        count += 1
    print('stop')
    
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global running # to assing value to global variable (instead of local variable)
    
    if button == mouse.Button.left: 
        if pressed:
            if not running:  # to run only one `process`
                running = True
                threading.Thread(target=process).start()
        else:
            running = False

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I would have been stuck on this for ages if not for you!

Comment: @PorpoisesUnited then I just want to ask why you didn't accept it as an answer :) This is really helpful man..